# Deleting 'b' and duplicating 'a' in-place

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This is a homework task: given a string of **only** 'a', 'b' and 'c's, duplicate all 'a', delete all 'b's and leave the c's alone (i.e. just copy them in the new string).

I.e.

```
Input: "abbc"
Output: "aac"
```

This should be done in linear time. Extra points for doing it in-place in the same string.

I thought of the following:
allocate some space at the end of the string and create the final string there while keeping the index in the original string

(code in C++)

```
int main() {

  string str;
  str.resize(50);
  char chars[] = "abbc";
  size_t slen = sizeof(chars) - 1;
  copy(begin(chars), end(chars), str.begin());
  int j = 49;
  for (int i = slen - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (str[i] == 'a') {
      str[j] = 'a';
      str[--j] = 'a';
      --j;
    }
    else if (str[i] == 'c') {
      str[j] = 'c';
      --j;
    }
    // Nothing for b
  }
  ++j;
  str.erase(str.begin(), str.begin() + j);    
}
```

this seems to work but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it (indices are easy to mess up) and if I'm not overlooking something.

Comment: "this seems to work" - that's because you haven't tested it properly

Comment: I should have mentioned bugs in the code are also highly welcome. Notice that this hasn't be 100% robust (i.e. what about strings of 60 characters?) since it's a **homework** question, not an industry-strength-requiring question. Feedback is always welcome though.

Comment: `leave the c's alone` this means reducing adjacent `c` just to `c`? is your string made only of you `a`, `b`, and `c`'s?

Comment: @svs Edited the question

Comment: you can't do it in the same string. `aaa` would become `aaaaaa` meaning that you need double the space. it means resizing. it mean using additional memory and not only the additional given.

Comment: Hint for getting an in-place algorithm working: If the source pointer is always <= the destination pointer, you can do a single backward pass; if it's always >= the destination, you can do a single forward pass.  If you can't guarantee that either of these 2 conditions holds, you can't do an in-place transformation in a single pass.

Comment: @svs,  "aaabbb" could be turned into "aaaaaa" in-place though.  And you could even do it in a single pass, at cost of memory.  You just can't *always* reuse the original string.

Comment: @JulianFondren I know... I was talking about the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a new string, there is no need to do it backwards. Processing from the front will be clearer. Despite being homework you should strive for general code and avoid magic numbers in your code (like 49).

Ask yourself what's the longest possible output string. How can you compute it? Can you write code which can deal with any input string, or handle failures in a graceful manner (not crash)?

Comment: Thanks john. I forgot a small detail and added it to the question: there are extra points if I can do it in-place. That explains why I've been trying to mess around with those indices

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in-place is easy, if you don't need to expand the size of the string. You just need to realize that you can use two passes. `2*n` is just as linear as `n`.

In the first pass, you delete all the `'b'` characters by copying from an input index to an output index, only incrementing the output index if the character is not `'b'`. At the same time count the number of `'a'` characters.

At this point you have enough information to tell if the final string will be the same size or less than the original string, and you can do the appropriate error handling if not.

The second pass works from the end of the string to the beginning. Start with the input index being the end of the current string, and the output index being that plus the number of `'a'` characters that you counted earlier. Each time you copy an `'a'` you insert an extra and decrement the output index twice.